# Range in Query Design View Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a 'student' table with details of id,name,sex,age,year,gpa of students.
I have another table 'major' table with the ids of students and the course which the major in(dname).

[image: student table and major table]

I would like to find the difference in age between the oldest student and the youngest student majoring in 'Computer Sciences'. This has proved difficult for me since the total function does not include 'range'.

[image: total_function]

When I try to find the difference between the maximum and minimum age using 'expression' in the total function I get this error....."Your query does not include the specified expression 'age' as part of an aggregate function"

[image: error_image]

How should i go about this to find the difference between the maximum and minimum age?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Total:` from Group By to Expression and define the criteria in `Field:` (see below).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change the first field of the query as follows:

- Remove the criteria
- Replace the field name (`age`) with the formula `Max([age])-Min([age])`